# Build a PID controller

Tags: analog, pid-controller, homework

I am trying to implement values for the resistors and capacitors values for a PID controller with the following transfer function:

\$ H(s)=2.9 + \large {3.5\over s} \normalsize + 0.64s\$

[image: PID]

I do know that the formula for \$2.9 = \large {R _{f}\over R_{i}} + {C_{i} \over C_{f}}\$ and \$ 3.5 = \large{1 \over R_{i}C_{f}}\$ and \$ 0.64 = R_{f}C_{i}\$.

I've tried many values for the resistors and capacitors but with no success. Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: Where did you find the circuit? I'm curious why there's no DC feedback, but maybe you're just doing this on a theoretical level with ideal components.

Comment: You guess my answer. It's a theoretical question and all of the components are ideals

Comment: What do you mean with "no success"? Did you measure or simulate the circuit? Note that there is no dc negative feedback, which is a problem for such an "isolated" analysis. However, if this PID block is part of the control loop the missing DC feedback is NOT a problem.

Comment: What about power supplies? symmetrical?

Comment: @GeorgeTsirmpas You will have to consider that, given that this topology will not be able to implement those values, your teacher was testing you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is make a system of equations from which you can extract the values for the elements:

$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
K_p&=\frac{R_f}{R_i}+\frac{C_i}{C_f} \\
K_i&=\frac{1}{R_iC_f} \\
K_d&=R_fC_i
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

I used the generic terms to solve symbolically. Since you have 4 unknowns and only 3 equations, you can impose one of the values, say \$C_i\$, and then solve for the elements as a function of \$C_i\$:

$$\begin{align}
R_i&=\frac{K_p\pm\sqrt{K_p^2-4K_dK_i}}{2K_iC_i} \\
R_f&=\frac{K_d}{C_i} \\
C_f&=C_i\frac{K_p\mp\sqrt{K_p^2-4K_dK_i}}{2K_dK_i}
\end{align}$$

This means that in order to have real-valued results, the condition \$K_p^2\ge4K_dK_i\$ must be satisfied. In your case, \$K_p^2=2.9^2=8.41\$ and \$4K_dK_i=4\cdot 3.5\cdot 0.64=8.96\$, so \$K_p^2-4K_dK_i=-0.55\$. That means you'll be getting imaginary numbers, so you need to recalculate your PID terms. How did you end up with those values? Don't forget that the transfer function of the opamp is with a negative sign.

---

Just to make it clear why you'll never get *exactly* the response in your transfer function, here are the values for an imposed value of `Ci = 1`, for a range of values for `Kp = [2.5 : 0.1 : 3.5]` (I've omitted the conjugates):

```
[ 2.5 ]:  Ri= 0.3571-0.2352i , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 0.3675i+0.558 
[ 2.6 ]:  Ri= 0.3714-0.2119i , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 0.3311i+0.5804 
[ 2.7 ]:  Ri= 0.3857-0.1846i , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 0.2885i+0.6027 
[ 2.8 ]:  Ri= 0.4-0.1512i , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 0.2362i+0.625 
[ 2.9 ]:  Ri= 0.4143-0.1059i , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 0.1655i+0.6473 
[ 3.0 ]:  Ri= 0.4571 , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 0.625 
[ 3.1 ]:  Ri= 0.3277 , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 0.8719 
[ 3.2 ]:  Ri= 0.2955 , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 0.9668 
[ 3.3 ]:  Ri= 0.273 , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 1.047 
[ 3.4 ]:  Ri= 0.2554 , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 1.119 
[ 3.5 ]:  Ri= 0.2409 , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 1.186
```

and magnitudes:

```
[ 2.5 ]:  Ri= 0.4276 , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 0.6682 
[ 2.6 ]:  Ri= 0.4276 , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 0.6682 
[ 2.7 ]:  Ri= 0.4276 , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 0.6682 
[ 2.8 ]:  Ri= 0.4276 , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 0.6682 
[ 2.9 ]:  Ri= 0.4276 , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 0.6682 
[ 3.0 ]:  Ri= 0.4571 , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 0.625 
[ 3.1 ]:  Ri= 0.3277 , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 0.8719 
[ 3.2 ]:  Ri= 0.2955 , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 0.9668 
[ 3.3 ]:  Ri= 0.273 , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 1.047 
[ 3.4 ]:  Ri= 0.2554 , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 1.119 
[ 3.5 ]:  Ri= 0.2409 , Rf= 0.64 , Cf= 1.186
```

Notice how the complex numbers stop when \$K_p\ge 3\$, and how the magnitudes are unchanged until then. That's where the conditions has passed \$K_p=\sqrt{4K_dK_i}=\sqrt{4\cdot 3.5\cdot 0.64}=2.993\$. To verify, here's a plot of the difference between a proper transfer function (`V(a)`) and the magnitudes of the values for your PID (`V(c)`) implemented with the topology from your picture:

[image: test]

There is a small differene in the magnitude, and that's because the difference between your value, 2.9, and the critical point, 2.993, is small. If \$K_p=1.9\$, the values for the elements would be unchanged (their magnitudes, even though it's not proper to think this way), and the difference will be larger:

[image: test2]

This is why I said that if you are forced to choose this topology, in particular, then you will be limited to a certain ratio between \$K_p\$ and the other two. But, for example, if you use a parallel topology, it would work for any values. Or if you use an inductor in series with \$C_f\$ and give up \$C_i\$ (or emulated inductor).

Comment: it was given to me by my professor

Comment: @GeorgeTsirmpas Even if you use negative values for Kp, Ki, and Kd in the system of equations (given that H(s)<0 for that opamp configuration), you still get complex numbers. OTOH, if you consider a *different configuration*, for example a parallel one, then it's perfectly possible. Are you sure you're required to use *that* particular PID? Or are you really required to just implement *some* PID, whichever one, with those values?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the reasons why I said you won't achieve that transfer function with that topology.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @GeorgeTsirmpas If you think this answers your question, then select it with the check mark. This will mean that others, in the future, when searching for similar problems, will see this question with an accepted answer.